# Facing [rtsp @ 000002aa9df0cb80] method SETUP failed: 500 Internal Server Error , while streaming rtsp camera in opencv

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp

Getting **[rtsp @ 000002aa9df0cb80] method SETUP failed: 500 Internal Server Error** when i try to stream rtsp camera in opencv python but after sometime it works fine for few minutes and does not works again,how do i overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 means that your rtsp Server has an issue.

Check logs on that server to know what happen. If its an IP camera try an Firmware Update. Thats not an issue of opencv is more an issue of your rtsp Server. You can double check if this also happen with VLC.